# Cell Editing inside ag-grid v.3.x.x

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have a button outside a grid in Angular 1.6.x. When I press it a corresponding function `startEditingCell()` should run, but instead inside **gridOptions.api** there is no **startEditingCell** function.

At the same time many other function are presented inside of api.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: have you defined gridOptions in the script?a little more code would be nice!

Comment: from the changelog for v5.4.x: "Enhancement: added API for startEditing()."... solution: upgrade to have the most recent features

Comment: @JarodMoser, thanks, solved it with an update.